# Queries to match substring in elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I have a field with mapping :

```
{
"type" : "text",
    "fields" : {
      "keyword" : {
        "type" : "keyword",
        "ignore_above" : 256
      }
    }
}
```

One of the document has value for the above field as "abcdef".
What kind of ES query should be used to match this document when searching for "def"?

I have tried match, prefix queries.

Comment: have you tried wildcard query? see below link for more details. https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-wildcard-query.html

Comment: nope, I will try. Is there any other type of query that would work? Other than wildcard or regex?

Comment: Could you add the JSON for the queries you have tried, please.